# View units in ExtJS 4 MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, view, window, extjs4

How in an ExtJS 4 MVC single web page application we can identify Views?
Is it a good practice to  consider each Ext.Window as a View unit? (one folder for each Window in app/view folder)
What is best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using single folder for each Window could be a nigthmare.

The concept is not for each window but for each entity (or model).

Having a folder for each model's views is the point.

For example, you have 3 entitites (models) in your application, sat Customer, Invoice, Payment your should have 3 subfolders in view main folder, one for each model. Inside each folder are the views used for CRUD for each model: List and Edit. If you have another views for the same model you should put in their respective folder (inquiry, charts, etc.).

I been working in a payroll application and my rule is use soubfolders as packages as I do in Java. I group related views in the same "package" even if is not for only one model. For example, I have a folder for all "catalog" models (depts, jobs, etc.), another for payroll processing and so.

The MVC of ExtJS is very similar to Ruby on Rails.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should read these before starting your application

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131671-Advanced-MVC-Best-Practices

http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-2

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.